# Сохранение цветов при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript

Что нужно прописать, чтобы при обновлении страницы цвета,
которые были изменены при ширине окна браузера сохранялись, а не сбрасывались.

То есть, чтобы красный и синий цвет **при обновлении страницы сохранялись.**  Чтобы понять, что за синий и красный цвет, попробуйте изменить ширину окна браузера =)

```js
let Button = document.querySelector(".Button");
let Text = document.querySelector(".Text");

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
Button.style.background = 'red';
Text.style.background = 'blue';
});
```

```css
.Block1{
width: 400px;
height:100px;
background: orange;
position:relative;
margin:50px;
}

.Button{
padding: 20px;
background:gray;
font-size:25px;
text-align:center;
width: 100px;
margin-left: 120px;
margin-top: 15px;
position:absolute;
user-select: none;
}

.Block2{
width: 600px;
height:150px;
background: orange;
position:relative;
margin:50px;
}

.Text{
padding: 20px;
background:white;
font-size:25px;
text-align:center;
margin-left: 130px;
margin-top: 35px;
position:absolute;
user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Main_block">

<div class ="Block1">
<div class ="Button"> КНОПКА</div>
</div>

<div class ="Block2">
<div class ="Text"> Я тебе покушать принес =) </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитайте о [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Вам придётся при каждом изменение делать запись в `localStorage`, а при каждой загрузке страницы получать запись и проводить изменения.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  Button.style.background = 'red';
  Text.style.background = 'blue';
  
  // Запишем
  localStorage.setItem('button-color', 'red');
  localStorage.setItem('text-color', 'blue');
});
```

И при загрузке отобразим:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  let Button = document.querySelector(".Button");
  let Text = document.querySelector(".Text");

  // Получим
  let ButtonColor = localStorage.getItem('button-color');
  let TextColor = localStorage.getItem('text-color');
  
  // Отобразим
  if(ButtonColor) Button.style.background = ButtonColor;
  if(TextColor) Text.style.background = TextColor;
});
```

Comment: Благодарю, а я и не знал про localStorage =)